# Multiplication with 2 objects that may have a variation in one label in NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, express, collections

I have 2 objects:

```
totalGridConso [ 
  { horoseason: 'HPH', value: 0 },
  { horoseason: 'HCH', value: 0 },
  { horoseason: 'HPE', value: 3498.54 },
  { horoseason: 'HCE', value: 4460.99 }
]


billedkWh [ 
  { horoseason: 'BASE', value: NaN },
  { horoseason: 'HPH', value: 8.4370003 },
  { horoseason: 'HCH', value: 5.5939999 },
  { horoseason: 'HPB', value: 5.0570002 },
  { horoseason: 'HCB', value: 3.3499999 }
]
```

What is important to mention is that I can match `HPE` with `HPB` and `HCE` with `HCB`, it is like old label, and new label, but the value is the same.

Now, I would like to make

```
const HTVar = billedkWh.map(x => {
            const HTVal = totalGridConso.find(it => hasSameHoroseason(it, x))
            return {
                horoseason: x.horoseason,
                value: typeof HTVal != 'undefined' ? HTVal.value * x.value / 100 : null
            }
        })
```

So I can get something similar to :

```
const HTVar = [
             {horoseason: "BASE", value: totalGridConso.find(it => it.horoseason === "BASE").value * billedKWh.find(it => it.horoseason === "BASE") / 100},
             {horoseason: "HPH", value: totalGridConso.find(it => it.horoseason === "HPH").value * billedKWh.find(it => it.horoseason === "HPH") / 100},
             {horoseason: "HCH", value: totalGridConso.find(it => it.horoseason === "HCH").value * billedKWh.find(it => it.horoseason === "HCH") / 100},
             {horoseason: "HPB", value: totalGridConso.find(it => it.horoseason === "HPE").value * billedKWh.find(it => it.horoseason === "HPB") / 100},
             {horoseason: "HCB", value: totalGridConso.find(it => it.horoseason === "HCE").value * billedKWh.find(it => it.horoseason === "HCB") / 100},
        ]
```

with `hasSameHoroseason(it, x)`

```
function hasSameHoroseason(it, x) {
    // In files, sometime the we find HPB, sometimes we find HPE
    // In files, sometime the we find HCB, sometimes we find HCE
    return it.horoseason === x.horoseason
        || (it.horoseason === "HPE" && it.horoseason === "HPB")
        || (it.horoseason === "HPB" && it.horoseason === "HPE")
        || (it.horoseason === "HCE" && it.horoseason === "HCB")
        || (it.horoseason === "HCB" && it.horoseason === "HCE")
        ;
}
```

The result should be

```
result [ 
  { horoseason: 'BASE', value: null },
  { horoseason: 'HPH', value: 0 },
  { horoseason: 'HCH', value: 0 },
  { horoseason: 'HPE', value: 176.92 }, // 3498.54×5.057÷100
  { horoseason: 'HCE', value: 14944.2718901 } // 4460.99×3,34999÷100
]
```

But I get:

```
undefined
{ horoseason: 'HPH', value: 0 }
{ horoseason: 'HCH', value: 0 }
undefined
undefined
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: `value: null` Do you mean `value: NaN`, since that's what's in the original object?

Comment: `it.horoseason === "HPE" && it.horoseason === "HPB"` the problem is with this logic but I'm not sure exactly what you need. Is it `it.horoseason === "HPE" && x.horoseason === "HPB"? Because right now you want the *same* property to be equal to two different values.

Comment: @VLAZ My bad ! code was ok, but I needed to change the second it. to x. -->  (it.horoseason === "HPE" && x.horoseason === "HPB"). You can put it as answer

Comment: :D I had a brief look and had to restart the PC. Yeah, now that I actually saw the logic, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code

```
return it.horoseason === x.horoseason
    || (it.horoseason === "HPE" && it.horoseason === "HPB")
    || (it.horoseason === "HPB" && it.horoseason === "HPE")
    || (it.horoseason === "HCE" && it.horoseason === "HCB")
    || (it.horoseason === "HCB" && it.horoseason === "HCE")
```

When you try to match different values you are actually checking the property on `it` both times, so the code tries to check if `it.horoseason` is equal to both `"HPE"` and to `"HPB"` at the same time.

The correct logic is to check both objects:

```
return it.horoseason === x.horoseason
    || (it.horoseason === "HPE" && x.horoseason === "HPB")
    || (it.horoseason === "HPB" && x.horoseason === "HPE")
    || (it.horoseason === "HCE" && x.horoseason === "HCB")
    || (it.horoseason === "HCB" && x.horoseason === "HCE")
```

If you need to add more cases in the future, you can improve this by adding a table for equalities. That would help as it's easier to maintain:

```js
function hasSameHoroseason(it, x) {
    const commonHPE_HPB = Symbol("HPE_HPB");
    const commonHCE_HCB = Symbol("HCE_HPB");
    const tableOfEqualities = {
      "HPE": commonHPE_HPB,
      "HPB": commonHPE_HPB,
      "HCE": commonHCE_HCB,
      "HCB": commonHCE_HCB
    }
    const itNormalised = tableOfEqualities[it.horoseason] || it.horoseason;
    const xNormalised = tableOfEqualities[x.horoseason] || x.horoseason;
    return itNormalised === xNormalised;
}

test("foo", "bar") //false
test("HPE", "bar") //false
test("HPE", "HPE") //true
test("HPE", "HPB") //true
test("HCE", "HCB") //true
test("HPE", "HCB") //false

function test(a, b) {
  console.log(`Values:
    "${a}"
    "${b}" 
considered equal:`, 
    hasSameHoroseason( 
      { horoseason: a },
      { horoseason: b }
    )
  )
}
```

The normalisation step will map HPE and HPB to the same value, so they can be directly converted. Same with HCE/HCB. I've used a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) here as it is quite appropriate, you will never get clashes with other values that way.

You can also extract the normalisation logic as well as the table of values separately and you only need to add items to the table that way, you never need to change the actual algorithm.

```js
const commonHPE_HPB = Symbol("HPE_HPB");
const commonHCE_HCB = Symbol("HCE_HPB");
const tableOfEqualities = {
  "HPE": commonHPE_HPB,
  "HPB": commonHPE_HPB,
  "HCE": commonHCE_HCB,
  "HCB": commonHCE_HCB
}

function normalise(val) {
  return tableOfEqualities[val] || val;
}

function hasSameHoroseason(it, x) {
    const itNormalised = normalise(it.horoseason);
    const xNormalised = normalise(x.horoseason);
    return itNormalised === xNormalised;
}

test("foo", "bar") //false
test("HPE", "bar") //false
test("HPE", "HPE") //true
test("HPE", "HPB") //true
test("HCE", "HCB") //true
test("HPE", "HCB") //false

function test(a, b) {
  console.log(`Values:
    "${a}"
    "${b}" 
considered equal:`, 
    hasSameHoroseason( 
      { horoseason: a },
      { horoseason: b }
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for the tip !